# Can we include both named and unnamed parameters in class constructors typescript?

Tags: typescript

This is how we do it in dart, I need a similar example in typescript

```
class Person{
final String name;
final double age, height, weight;

//constructor
Person(this.name,{this.age, this.height, this.weight})
}

//initialization
Person person = Person('Bruce Wayne', height: 172, weight: 82, age: 25);
```

Comment: JavaScript/TypeScript doesn't have named parameters, only positional parameters. Typically the workaround is to pass an _object_.

Comment: Yeah, the TypeScript way of doing this would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w16oXN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?